# AWS CloudFormation "Update Stack" and "Create Change Set" are disabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The stack creation failed with ROLLBACK_COMPLETE, yet any option to change the stack or the provided parameters is greyed out.

I know I can delete the stack and start again, but I don't understand conditions behind "Update Stack" and "Create Change Set" being disabled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If stack creation has failed then the stack doesn't exist, so you can't update it. `DELETE STACK` on a stack that has failed to be created only removes the reference to it which is used to hold the error status - that's the only thing you can do with it.

Comment: So do we start again?